# XPath to CSS selector on YouTube

Tags: java, python, selenium, css-selectors, microsoft-edge

For some time now, I've been trying to collect data from youtube by using selenium to run videos automatically.

But in Edge run in some troubles cause Microsoft doesn't support Xpath,
so I understand that it support CSS selector.

So if someone can help me to find how to change quality by CSS it will be great, by the web Microsoft web driver don't support Python (wrote in their web so I use java)

I included the code so far and how I did it in chrome with Xpath in python.

Here's the code in Java:

```
import java.io.File;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.Window;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;


public class testEdge {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File file = new File("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Web Driver\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());


        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.edge();
        EdgeDriver driver = new EdgeDriver(capabilities);

        Window window = driver.manage().window();
        window.maximize();



        driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pRpeEdMmmQ0");
       WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,2);
       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("#movie_player > div.ytp-chrome-bottom > div.ytp-chrome-controls > div.ytp-right-controls > button.ytp-button.ytp-settings-button")));

        driver.findElementByCssSelector("#movie_player > div.ytp-chrome-bottom > div.ytp-chrome-controls > div.ytp-right-controls > button.ytp-button.ytp-settings-button").click();;

       // wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("#ytp-main-menu-id > div:nth-child(4) > div.ytp-menuitem-label")));

      driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ytp-main-menu-id > div:nth-child(4) > div.ytp-menuitem-label")).click();;

      driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(":contains('text')")).click();;


     // driver.findElement(By.className("ytp-menu-label-secondary")).click();

        // #ytp-main-menu-id > div:nth-child(1)
    }
}
```

The query for getting the quality in XPath in Python:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'"+video_quality+"')]").click()
```

Comment: this is which button xpath which you have mentioned?

Comment: The quality, you open the player menu bar and choose quality, the quality I want to choose with CSS selector

Answer (score 0):

text attribute not supported in CSS3 Hence also not supported in webdriver. Apart from this backtracking is also not supported in CSS.

Apart from all other css locator are convertible to xpath. But till now it is manual process. You can past your xpath's for which you want css locators. I will try to answer you